# Replacing default forms in django-postman via urlpatterns and views

Tags: django, django-urls, django-class-based-views

[django-postman docs](https://django-postman.readthedocs.io/en/latest/views.html#forms) say that you can replace the default forms in views with this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('postman.views',
    # ...
    url(r'^write/(?:(?P<recipients>[^/#]+)/)?$',
        WriteView.as_view(form_classes=(MyCustomWriteForm, MyCustomAnonymousWriteForm)),
)
```

But what is `patterns`?  Where do I import that from, and where would this code go?  In the project's urls.py?

My project level **urls.py** currently includes django-postman, as recommended in the docs, like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
  ...
  url("r'messages/', include('postman.urls', namespace='postman'),
]
```

So the custom url pattern should be overwriting the default that will already be included in urls.py.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a code for `urls.py`. However, it's quite outdated.
The modern version would look like:

```
from django.urls import re_path

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^write/(?:(?P<recipients>[^/#]+)/)?$',
        WriteView.as_view(form_classes=(MyCustomWriteForm, MyCustomAnonymousWriteForm)),
]
```

**Edit**

I guess you're including postman urls in your root urls.py, then you can do something like this to overwrite one of them:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    re_path(r'^messages/write/(?:(?P<recipients>[^/#]+)/)?$',
        WriteView.as_view(form_classes=(MyCustomWriteForm, MyCustomAnonymousWriteForm)),
    path('messages/', include('postman.urls')),
]
```

Comment: Thanks!  Where does the namespace go?  it looks like this would appear in the root url, instead of the 'postman' namespace?